# Impossible fallback return cause a coverage issue. Ts error otherwise

Tags: typescript, testing, code-coverage

```
type Status = "default" | "hover" | "active" | "disabled"
type StatusMap = {
    [key in Status]?: boolean
}
const stack: Status[] = ['disabled', 'active', 'hover', 'default']
function getStatus(props: StatusMap): Status {
    for (let i = 0; i <= stack.length; i++) {
        const s = stack[i]
        if (props[s]) {
            return s
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ts code which causes the problems:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Ts believe there is a chance to return `undefined`, However it is not possible in a real use case. Because at least one key will present in `StatusMap` even though it is noted as optional.

Maybe a quick fix is to return a default value so that ts will not complain. However, the default return will never be hit which causes a coverage issue.

What is the possible solution

Answer (score 0):

The other possible solution is to change function return type to `Status | undefined`. However this can cause another errors in places, where `getStatus` is used. If you are really sure that `StatusMap` will have at least one value in places, where `getStatus` will be called, then you can change `(props: StatusMap)` to `(props: Required<StatusMap>)`. I believe this will prevent all the TS errors here)

Comment: I think you are on the right track, we need to tell ts one of the props will present somehow. However, your solution does not work in a syntax perspective, still error

Answer (score 0):

I say there must be one of the keys present for a reason. I add `default:true` before passing in, so in the type declaration

```
type StatusMap = {
  [key in TabStatus]?: boolean
} & { default: true }
```

Comment: I'd rather `return 'default'` from the function, that would solve the issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKAiAJhAZvEgDbBZQA+2AFgPYBuEATuVVvAMbACWjr2ObingAjYhBxYAsAChQkWAmQoAsvDAYoAb1lQ9UANoBrCCCjcAdosSoAugH4AXFBG1a4+BdkBfWR1oWKMBQQZxGznA2KAa2mgYA5ILCYhLxADRQ8Zw8jOmZdIxMeYkERKTxtrL4SBZc3AFQAOYQwJHKABRgTLRgKBFKqGpgAJT9Udq6+vi0TFDt4sHcmgAMANzmUAA8mKEcRgB04haNwNTr3ADUF8MTMvr3UP6BwWg7CHsG3JV3D3rc+HMuj1oihbDcdD9fvcmC0kEwrChVpNfr5IVBUdDYfDMnhCCRgPEkTJvEA

Comment: @tanmay the problem is that the `return` statement will never trigger which cause a test coverage issue